# Data Binding with Angular 2 & Inline SVG

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I have an SVG image, parts of which I change dynamically depending on responses from an API call. One aspect I change is the colour of different elements within the SVG, which I can handle somewhat cleanly via applying different CSS classes. However there are also text elements that I would like to change.

I have this currently working by inlining the full SVG image into my component template and picking out the parts I wish to bind to the model. However, this means that any time I want to edit the raw SVG image I need to copy/paste the SVG markup back into the template and reapply these bindings.

Ideally what I would do is keep the SVG as an external file, then inline the SVG as part of the build process so I can avoid sandboxing (something I can currently do), but I also want to dynamically apply the data bindings via a selector (e.g. id/class associated with each SVG sub-element) after the SVG is inlined. Two solutions I've come up with would be to create a directive that would do some DOM manipulation to associate the relative elements with the values I want to set, or to modify the SVG tags in the build process post-inline to add the Angular binding syntax here. Neither option seems great to me.

Is there another way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Having the same problem, Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem as well. Here's hoping you guys can let me know if you found any workarounds or alternatives :)